# Android studio - how to use long click on a button

Tags: java, android-studio

I have a Button and when I click it it plays a Sound. How to use longpress to turn sound ( on and off ), so basically first tap should play a sound, second tap should stop it.

[MainActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqZJP.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onLongClickListener`:

```
Button button;
button = findViewById(R.id.<your_button_id>);
button.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        //your code goes here
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add onLongClickListener to your button and implement the method onLongClick in your main activity. 
for example:

```
public class MainActivity implements View.OnLongClickListener
```

after you implement the onLongClickListener you override the function onLongCLick

```
 @Override
public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
    return false;
}
```

And finally you need to set onLongClickListener to your button

```
        btn.setOnLongClickListener(this);
```

In order to make the sound on and of just hold a global boolean variable which is called 
private boolean isPlaying;

When it is long pressed once you set it to true, and when it is called again set it to false.

and stop your sound.

Comment: You don't duplicate anything, just add the implementation of the interface after your already existing MainActivity class.

Comment: Can you describe the steps better please ?

Comment: 1) Go to your MainActivity class and add this line instead of your class line:  
 public class MainActivity implements View.OnLongClickListener.                               2) implement the methods of the interface, press alt enter on the error you get and press implement methods.                                                                                     3) in your onCreate() add the following line:  button.setOnLongClickListener(this);